# Loooking for a command similar to time, but exiting if the time exceeds a limit

Tags: shell, ubuntu, unix

I want to benchmark a tool. I am using the usual time command. But if it takes more than 1 hour to run, the tool is clearly too bad, and I want to exit immediately and be notified on the stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine `time` (does the timing) with the `timeout` utility from coreutils (does the killing).

Example:

```
$ time timeout 1 sleep 4
  Command exited with non-zero status 124
  0.00user 0.00system 0:01.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 2012maxresident)
```